# CSS selector equivalent to this nested or embedded XPath?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

There is a type of XPath like this

```
//div[span[a[@title='foo']]]
```

where it matches & returns the div (not the hyperlink) that contains a span, which in turn contains a hyperlink with title "foo".

is there a CSS selector format equivalent to this?

I gave it a short trying to convert to CSS, and if there is an equivalent, I don't know how to map it correctly.

Comment: Css doesn't have parent selector yet

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I thought so, just wanted confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Selectors don't have the kind of predicate that XPath does, and there isn't a way to ascend an element's hierarchy from the deepest element (in this case your `a[@title='foo']`), i.e. [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I thought so, just wanted confirmation.